# Why does Blend/Visual Studio always generate ResourceDictionary "Source" Incorrectly?

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2017, resourcedictionary, blend

## Brief

I'm starting to go crazy. I've been chasing this issue for about a day now and I can't figure out how to *easily* resolve it. So I figured I'd drive you all crazy with this too (hopefully you have better luck than me).

**Note**: A link to a zipped version of the project is provided below in the *Edit* section.

---

## Project Structure

I have a C# project structure that resembles the following:

```
├ Shared                      Solution folder (containing shared projects)
├──── Shared.UI               Shared.UI - Shared Project
├──────── Style.xaml          Resource Dictionary xaml file
├ MyProject                   Solution folder (containing related projects)
├──── MyProject.UI            MyProject.UI - WPF App Project
├──────── MainWindow.xaml     The xaml file using Style.xaml
```

The solution contains multiple projects organized by *purpose*, thus `MyProject` contains multiple projects. Project structure must be maintained **as is**. Also note that the solution folders also exist in explorer (not that it should make a difference).

The names of my projects are `Shared.UI` and `MyProject.UI` explicitly. I have a reference to *Shared.UI* in the *MyProject.UI* project.

**Note**: The shared project *Shared.UI* must remain a shared project. We have classes that use `ifdef` for platform-specific code (which is not available in PCL)

---

## Code

#### Style.xaml

For testing purposes, I've been using an empty Resource Dictionary as follows.

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Shared.UI">

</ResourceDictionary>
```

#### MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="MyProject.UI.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject.UI"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/MyProject.UI;component/Shared.UI/Style.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

---

## Issue

Everything displays correctly in Blend/Visual Studio, no issues occur and everything is properly linked. When you debug the solution (click [image: Start]), however, you'll get the following exception:

[image: Exception]

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException occurred   HResult=0x80131501
>   Message='Set property 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.Source' threw
>   an exception.' Line number '12' and line position '6'.
>   Source=   StackTrace:    at
>   System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader,
>   IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean
>   skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings
>   settings, Uri baseUri)    at
>   System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader,
>   Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel
>   accessLevel, Uri baseUri)    at
>   System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext
>   parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)    at
>   System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri
>   resourceLocator)    at MyProject.UI.MainWindow.InitializeComponent()
>   in
>   C:\Users\ctoscher\source\repos\Test\MyProject\MyProject.UI\MainWindow.xaml:line
>   1
>
> Inner Exception 1: IOException: Cannot locate resource
>   'shared.ui/style.xaml'.

The important part is `IOException: Cannot locate resource 'shared.ui/style.xaml'.`

#### Replicating the Issue

To replicate this issue, you'll need to open *MainWindow.xaml* in Blend or Visual Studio. Once in the IDE, click on the ResourceDictionary line that contains the `Source` attribute (the line that follows)

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="/MyProject;component/Shared.UI/Styles.xaml"/>
```

In the *Properties* panel, set the Source to `Styles.xaml` (this should already be selected since my code above sets this attribute).

#### Solving the Error

The Source URI is set to `/MyProject.UI;component/Shared.UI/Style.xaml`. If you remove `/Shared.UI` from the string, such that you're left with `/MyProject.UI;component/Style.xaml`, and run it, it works!

I've also attempted to change the *Build Action* for `Styles.xaml` to every other action; no other method seems to work "out of the box" (without the aforementioned modification).

---

## Question Time

- How can `ResourceDictionary` with its `Source` attribute be **properly** linked/generated in Blend/Visual Studio so as to not create these issues in the first place? (I understand my workaround is allowing my application to run, but how can I fix this annoyance so that my team and I don't have to edit the link every single time?)

I appreciate those of you who actually took the time to read all this. I know this is a long post, <s>however, without creating a zip of the solution,</s> this is as much pertinent information as I can give you.

---

### Edit

#### Solution Download

I realize posting files are usually frowned upon, but I feel it may help with the resolution of this question. [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IbkHgu_Ora6NIaZFNZPh4Vr6Z-vUj30E/view?usp=sharing) is a link to the project (zipped).

#### Updates

As per [@Yuri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2250405/yuri-s) (in the comments below/chat transcript):

> Here is my thoughts. When you open xaml in Blend it sees SharedUI
>   project and assumes it is a DLL as it doesn't see MyProjectUI. Because
>   SharedUI is a shared project all files are linked directly to
>   ProjectUI, so when you remove SharedUI from path it works.

The issue likely exists as a bug in Blend/Visual Studio not adjusting the method for link generation for shared projects, but if anyone has any suggestions as to how this can be resolved, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't it read `Source="/Shared.UI;component/Styles.xaml"/>` instead?  After all it is **Shared.UI** that contains the style not **MyProject.UI**.  Anyway, it's generally convention to place all styling in your **App.xaml** rather than specifying it each time for all views

Comment: **Mind explaining the downvote?** My question fully complies with [Help Center > Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). I am not seeking debugging help, this problem can be reproduced, it is not homework, nor is it asking for a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource, it's not considered general computing hardware/software, and it's not regarding professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration. The question is not subjective, I've created a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example, the title summarizes the problem... Please explain.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158985/discussion-between-ctwheels-and-yuri-s).

Comment: It's just an issue in Blend and VS where multiple projects being used aren't mapped correctly in paths for resources in XAML.  I've been dealing with this for years...  This also happens with image paths etc.  It sucks but you just have to manually fix it fro now.  If you find a fix let me know also.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII I guess there's no light at the end of the tunnel... Thanks for your reply. If I do get an answer for this, I'll be sure to let you know.

Comment: Why sometimes your file is named `Style.xaml` and others `Styles.xaml` 
Can that be related with the issue? Maybe some reference not properly updated?

Comment: @alseether those are simply typos in the question. If you download the project from the link you should see that they're all synonymous.